# Subtract subsequent row from previous row based on User

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data and I want to subtract current row from previous row based on the UserID. I tried the code below is not given me what I want

```
DECLARE @DATETBLE TABLE (UserID INT, Dates DATE)
INSERT INTO @DATETBLE VALUES
(1,'2018-01-01'), (1,'2018-01-02'), (1,'2018-01-03'),(1,'2018-01-13'),
(2,'2018-01-15'),(2,'2018-01-16'),(2,'2018-01-17'), (5,'2018-02-04'),
(5,'2018-02-05'),(5,'2018-02-06'),(5,'2018-02-11'), (5,'2018-02-17')


;with cte as (
      select UserID,Dates, row_number() over (order by UserID) as seqnum
      from @DATETBLE t
     )
select t.UserID,t.Dates, datediff(day,tprev.Dates,t.Dates)as diff
from cte t left outer join
     cte tprev
     on t.seqnum = tprev.seqnum + 1;
```

Current Output

```
UserID  Dates   diff
1   2018-01-01  NULL
1   2018-01-02  1
1   2018-01-03  1
1   2018-01-13  10
2   2018-01-15  2
2   2018-01-16  1
2   2018-01-17  1
5   2018-02-04  18
5   2018-02-05  1
5   2018-02-06  1
5   2018-02-11  5
5   2018-02-17  6
```

My Expected Output

```
  UserID    Dates   diff
    1   2018-01-01  NULL
    1   2018-01-02  1
    1   2018-01-03  1
    1   2018-01-13  10
    2   2018-01-15  NULL
    2   2018-01-16  1
    2   2018-01-17  1
    5   2018-02-04  NULL
    5   2018-02-05  1
    5   2018-02-06  1
    5   2018-02-11  5
    5   2018-02-17  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag (`sql-server-2008`) suggests me to use `APPLY` :

```
select t.userid, t.dates, datediff(day, t1.dates, t.dates) as diff
from @DATETBLE t outer apply
     ( select top (1) t1.*
       from @DATETBLE t1
       where t1.userid = t.userid and
             t1.dates < t.dates
       order by t1.dates desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Ah - was LAG() not available in MS SQL Server 2008?

Comment: @tbrookside. . . Analytical `lag()` function available from `SQL 2012 +`.

Comment: @tbrookside. . . You should not delete your answer, but instead you edit  with `SQL Server` version in which the `lag()` is available.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server version 2012 or higher, you could use `LAG()` with a partition by UserID:

```
SELECT UserID
     , DATEDIFF(dd,COALESCE(LAG_DATES, Dates), Dates) as diff

FROM

(
SELECT UserID
     , Dates
     , LAG(Dates) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Dates) as LAG_DATES

FROM @DATETBLE
) exp
```

This will give you a 0 value instead of a NULL value for the first date in the sequence though.

Since you tagged the post with SQL Server 2008, however, you may need to use a method that doesn't rely on this windowed function.